# Postgres advantages of BOOLEAN NOT NULL vs BOOL with TRUE/NULL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, null

I want to add a flag to a frequently accessed table in my database. It is logically a boolean that is set for a very small portion of the records <0.1%. I want to ensure that I am not causing a significant performance cost unnecessarily.

Reading the docs and other answers it seems to me that a `BOOLEAN NOT NULL` column will take 1 byte in every row (amortized) whereas if I instead use a `BOOLEAN` that is `NULL` for most rows it will only take 1 bit (amortized, in the boolean bitmap) and one byte where it is set to `TRUE`.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using `NULL` instead of `FALSE` assuming that I do not and will never need a tristate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be saving a byte per row, and possibly even more, if the next column is of a type with a *type alignment* greater than 1.

However, the NULL might make your queries more complicated or harder to read, which might be worse than the benefit of saving a little disk space.

I'd decide based on the latter: if your queries are still efficient and readable using NULL values, go for it, otherwise don't.

Comment: NB Sounds like a candidate for a partial index.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Absolutely. But that works with NULL as well as `FALSE`.